# Hard improper integral question

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{\ln x}\mathrm{dx}$ determine the convergence or divergence of the integral.

So I tried to distinguish the interval of the integral:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\cos x}{\ln x}\mathrm{dx}+\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{\ln x}\mathrm{dx}$$

And the first integral is proper since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \dfrac{\cos x}{\ln x}=0$. But the other ones I can't evaluate those. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I see why I separate it wrongly, thanks for feedback I will change this.

Comment: But now I don't know how to evaluate at x=1

Comment: Do you know the Lebesgue criterion for integrability? It requires that the integrand must be bounded on the interval to be integrable.

Comment: Intuitively, the second integral should converge because its behaviour is similar to that of an alternating series. Do you think you could formalise this intuition into a rigorous proof?

Comment: No, I don't know Lebesgue Criterion I have got one week for that theorem. For the second comment I don't think that I can do.

Answer (score 4):

Both integrals diverge. Note that
$$ \frac{\cos z}{\log z} = \frac{\cos 1}{z-1} + \left(\frac{\cos 1}{2} - \sin 1\right) + O(|z-1|)$$
In particular,
$$\lim_{a\to 1^-} \int_0^a \frac{\cos x}{\log x} dx =-\infty$$
and for any $c>1$,
$$\lim_{b\to 1^+} \int_b^c \frac{\cos x}{\log x} dx =+\infty$$
so
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\log x} dx$$
has an $\infty-\infty$ singularity at $x=1$. However, it is true that the improper integral
$$\int_c^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\log x} dx$$
converges for any $c>1$. You can show this by considering the alternating sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}^{(k+\frac{3}{2})\pi}\frac{\cos x}{\log x} dx$$

It is interesting to note, that if $\cos x$ were to be replaced by $\cos \frac{\pi x}{2}$, the singularity at $x=1$ would be removed, so the similar-looking integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}}{\log x} dx$$
is actually convergent.